# How to implement accessibility in java

Tags: java, swing, accessibility

I am visually impaired and am developing some java GUIs and I would find it extremely ironic if my GUIs were not accessible to myself.  So anyone out there who can help it would be great if someone could give some advice/examples of how to implement accessibility in java.

I am looking for how to make,
Combo boxes accessible,
tabbedPanes,
buttons,
*tables* (adding descriptions),
and anything else you feel is important.
Also, could someone explain what is the getAccessibleContext method and how to use it?
Some of these such as buttons appear to be already quite accessible but my test combo boxes I have made are not interpreted so well with my speech reader.

Any information on any of the above would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much

PS using eclipse to right the code if that is useful

Comment: Please focus title/tags: e.g. "in Swing"? Also, asking for resources/advice/examples generally isn't the best way to get a good SO response - do some initial research and bring back your findings in a more focused question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

there is  tutorial accessibility which explains what a accessibleContext. 
the link: [How to Support Assistive Technologies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/access.html)

Comment: @SaadAttieh : Please also do have a look at [Java SE Desktop Accessibility](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136191.html)